# Unable to Fix Django NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: django, django-views

I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error when I try to pass two arguments from one view to another.  Here is the view that is passing the arguments:

```
# promotion/views.py
def enter_promo_code(request, template):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PromotionCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message_text, expiry_date = process_valid_promo_code(request.user, form.cleaned_data['promo_code'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('welcome-page-promo', \
                    kwargs={'message_text': message_text, 'expiry_date': expiry_date}))
    else:
        form = PromotionCodeForm(label_suffix="")
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Here is the receiving view.  Note that the two input arguments are optional.  The urlpatterns show that this view can be called with or without arguments.

```
# home/views.py
def welcome_page(request, template, message_text=None, expiry_date=None):
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    context = {'uid': request.user.id, 'account_type': account.type.account_type_cd, 'message_text': message_text, 'expiry_date': expiry_date}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Here are the urlpatterns for the receiving view:

```
# home/urls.py
url(r'^welcome/$',
    'home.views.welcome_page',
    {'template': 'welcome_page.html'},
    name='welcome-page'),

url(r'^welcome/(?P<message_text>\w{1,})/(?P<expiry_date>\w{1,})/$',
    'home.views.welcome_page',
    {'template': 'welcome_page.html'},
    name='welcome-page-promo'),
```

When I execute the promotion view, I get this error when the return HttpResponseRedirect command executes:

```
NoReverseMatch at /promotion/code/
Reverse for 'welcome-page-promo' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'message_text': u'Your promotion code was approved!  You will receive a one-year free trial membership which expires on ', 'expiry_date': 'Jul. 18, 2018'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['welcome/(?P<message_text>\\w{1,})/(?P<expiry_date>\\w{1,})/$']
```

I'm running this same code pattern in a different application in the project and it runs without error.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have the full message text in the url?

Comment: Yea, now that I look at it what I was trying to do was pretty stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here, one of design and one of implementation.

The design problem is that you probably shouldn't have such long text in your URLs. I believe Django will handle the argument escaping for you, but it's still not going to be the easiest pattern to work with. It looks to me like your `message_text` argument is likely to be static, or at least selected from a small number of possibilities. Most likely you should record it in your template, create a model for it and pass around the ID, or something along those lines. There's nothing wrong with passing dates around in a URI, although I prefer a simpler format like `2018-07-18` over `Jul. 18, 2018`, but if it's truly an expiration date you probably want to have a model for memberships and set it as an attribute there, then look it up it your welcome page view.

Putting that aside and looking at your implementation problem - your view regexps only match one or more characters from the `\w` class, which is defined as:

> When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

However, your args include characters like `!` and spaces. Use a regexp that matches your desired arguments - `[^/]+` is one, if you want to be forgiving. (`+` is more readable than `{1,}` in my opinion, but they mean the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks.  It would have been awhile before I had figured that out, if ever.  But as Sayse alluded to above, what I was trying to do what stupid in the first place.  This is not a question I'm proud of.